# Write the statement in symbolic language

Tags: logic

Consider the following statement: One plus the square of an odd natural number is divisible by a product of 2 consecutive natural numbers.

Write this in symbolic language. Is it true or false?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: I think its for all x belonging to the odd natural numbers there exists a y such that (1+x^2) is divisible by (y*y+1)) obviously this would be written with quantifiers

Comment: You may want to say, "for every $x$, there exists a $y$ such that $1 + (2x+1)^2$ is the product of $y$ and $y+1$," where $x$ and $y$ are natural numbers.

Answer (score 0):

A natural number is odd iff it is of the form $2n+1$, with $n$ a natural number.

So we are considering numbers of the form $(2n+1)^2 +1 = 4n^2 + 4n + 2 = 2(2n^2 + 2n +1)$, but $10$ cannot be written as any product of consecutive numbers, so the statement is false. Two consecutive integers are of the form $m$ and $m+1$, so the statement can be written as

$$\forall n \exists m: (2n+1)^2 + 1= m(m+1)$$

where quantors are over the natural numbers.